# How is an auto-generated c# client supposed to handle an API call that can return different types?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, autorest

I am consuming a service that has the following definition:

```
[HttpGet]
[SwaggerOperation(nameof(GetAnimal))]
[Route("{animalId:long}", Name = nameof(GetAnimal))]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(AnimalModel), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ErrorModel), StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
public Task<IActionResult> GetAnimal(string tenantId, long animalId)
{
    try
    {
        // Find the actual animal.. somewhere.

        return Ok(new AnimalModel());      

    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        return InternalServerError(new ErrorModel());
    }    
}
```

This seems to cause `autorest` to generate a C# client with an `object` as a return type (I guess because of the `ProducesResponseType` attribute being specified twice):

```
public async Task<HttpOperationResponse<object>> GetAnimalWithHttpMessagesAsync(string tenantId, long animalId, [..])
```

**Question**

What is the recommended way to handle an API that return different objects?

**Potential solutions**

- I could fix the client code and cast the result to find the right type (not good).
- I could modify the API (if possible) so that it returns only one object composed of the `AnimalModel` and the `ErrorModel` (could be better).

Comment: Or use the new `ActionResult<T>` and remove the produces response attribute altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ActionResult<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.1#actionresultt-type)

> ASP.NET Core 2.1 introduces the `ActionResult<T>` return type for Web API controller actions. It enables you to return a type deriving from `ActionResult` or return a specific type. `ActionResult<T>` offers the following benefits over the `IActionResult` type:
>
> - The `[ProducesResponseType]` attribute's `Type` property can be excluded. For example, `[ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(Product))]` is simplified to `[ProducesResponseType(200)]`. The action's expected return type is instead inferred from the `T` in `ActionResult<T>`.
> - Implicit cast operators support the conversion of both `T` and `ActionResult` to `ActionResult<T>`. `T` converts to `ObjectResult`, which means `return new ObjectResult(T);` is simplified to `return T;`.

Consider using the new `ActionResult<T>` and remove the produces response attribute
`Type` altogether.

```
[HttpGet]
[SwaggerOperation(nameof(GetAnimal))]
[Route("{animalId:long}", Name = nameof(GetAnimal))]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
public async Task<ActionResult<AnimalModel>> GetAnimal(string tenantId, long animalId) {
    try {
        // Find the actual animal.. somewhere...using await.

        var model = new AnimalModel();

        //populate model    

        return model;
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        return InternalServerError(new ErrorModel());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer (with the await fix ;)). I tried it: swagger does not list any return type anymore.